# How do you make a big Laplace Transform symbol

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel,color,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
Derivation of $ \mathscr {L} \{\int_0^{t} f(\tau)\,d\tau\} $

\end{document}
```

So far this is what I have but I'd like to use `\displaystyle` for the integral to make it look nicer since the top and bottom limits are kinda squished, but then the Laplace part is too small and I have no idea how to make it bigger

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You could load the `relsize` package and use the `\mathlarger` macro (once or repeatedly) to enlarge `\mathscr{L}`. In the third row of the following screenshot, the enlarged `\mathscr{L}` is generated by two calls to `\mathlarger`; don't overdo the enlarging stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,relsize,array}
\newcommand\Laplace{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathscr{L}}}}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{>{$}l<{$} c}
original form & 
\mathscr {L} \{\int_0^{t} f(\tau)\,d\tau\} \\[2ex]
displaystyle & 
\mathscr{L} \biggl\{\displaystyle\int_0^{t} \! f(\tau)\,d\tau\biggr\} \\[4ex]
enlarged $\mathscr{L}$, displaystyle & 
\Laplace \biggl\{\displaystyle\int_0^{t} \! f(\tau)\,d\tau\biggr\} \\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The packages [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry), [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), and [`cancel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) are not necessary.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - I've simplified the preamble per your suggestion.